# Identificar o tipo do telefone (fixo/celular)

Tags: javascript, tipo-de-conteúdo

Alguém saberia dizer se é possível identificar o tipo do telefone (fixo/celular) através do primeiro digito?

Por exemplo, o numero 6889-7777 é fixo ou celular? Preciso identificar o tipo do telefone antes do usuário terminar de preencher ele por completo.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Cara, eu não entendi a sua dúvida. O 9º dígito só existe pra números de celular.

Comment: @jbueno a duvida é se consigo identificar o tipo do telefone pelo primeiro numero, por exemplo numeros começados com 9 são celulares, numeros começados com 3 são fixos, entendeu ?

Comment: Nem todos os celulares comecam com 9, varias operadoras comeca com 8.. Voce nao consegue garantir isso

Comment: Sim, você consegue.

Comment: Você quer saber como fazer isso no código?

Comment: @leofontes, foi exatamente essa a duvida, se eu consigo ou não, pelas respostas parece bem contraditorio.

Comment: @Bacco, alterei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro agora =]

Comment: @DouglasNeves tou dando uma limpa nos comentários acima. Bom, pra Brasil, como eu disse, se começar por 9 é celular. Isso é padrão agora. Se tiver uma região que ainda não migrou, é coisa de poucos meses.

Comment: @Bacco, brigadão pela dica

Comment: @jbueno, editei a pergunta acho que ficou mais claro agora, precisava identificar se existe algum padrão já definido pra tipificar os números através do primeiro digito.

Comment: @Bacco Semana passada foi a última região. Agora tá no país todo.

Comment: @DouglasNeves Como o Bacco disse. Se começar por 9, é celular. Claro que isso pode mudar, mas aí é outra história

Comment: @leofontes Com o novo padrão, todos os números de celular começam por 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você precisa validar números atuais:
- iniciando por 9 seria móvel
- 7 é nextel (um outro "tipo" de móvel)
- os demais seriam fixos

Caso precise tratar histórico, aí depende do período que você tem armazenado, mas de forma genérica seria:
- primeiro dígito > 5 é móvel
- primeiro dígito < 5 é fixo 
- primeiro dígito =  5 pode ser fixo ou móvel
Esse último cenário se deve ao fato de que em um determinado momento, antes da implantação do nono dígito, a anatel liberou o uso dos números iniciados por 5 para a rede móvel, sendo que já existiam fixos iniciados por 5 (maioria dos cenários em SP)

Comment: Acabei utilizando essa lib para uma solução mais completa =]
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber